# How did scipy ver 0.18 scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline deal with values not strictly increasing?

Tags: python, scipy, version, interpolation

I have a program written in python 2.7.5 scipy 0.18.1 that is able to run scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline with arrays that are non-sequential. When I try to run the same program in python 2.7.14 / scipy 1.0.0 I get the following error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py", line 176, in **init**
    raise ValueError('x must be strictly increasing')

Usually I would just fix the arrays to remove the non-sequential values. But in this case I *need* to reproduce the exact same solution produced by the earlier version of python/scipy. Can anyone tell me how the earlier code dealt with the situation where the values were not sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC this was whatever the FITPACK (the fortran library the univariatespline class wraps) was doing. So the first stop would be to remove the check from your local scipy install and see if this does the trick

Comment: That's a decent suggestion. If it works I'll then need to consult FITPACK. Do you know where I might find the FITPACK code?

Comment: @DVC https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py#L70-L525 is python wrapper (cluck "source" in the scope docs); https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v1.4.1/scipy/interpolate/fitpack is the (scipy lightly patched) FITPACK code